# Can I use keycloak as a reverse proxy to authenticate requests from a server to a 3rd party API endpoint

Tags: rest, keycloak, openid-connect

Our application server (node.js) needs to communicate with a 3rd party API endpoint. The endpoint sits behind a reverse proxy that uses openid-connect authentication.

[The Keycloak docs say that Keycloak can be used to talk to a reverse proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/), but they are quite convoluted. Does that mean that it would be possible to use Keycloak on our side to handle authentication and make as openid-connect protected endpoint available? If so, how would you go about setting this up?